# wxPython analogue for MS List-View control

Tags: wxpython

Microsoft Windows provides a list-view control with different views (details, icons, list, tile): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I can't find how and if wxPython provides the same control, especially in the *multicolumn* "list" mode. Any suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `wx.ListCtrl` and its various style flags.  On Windows this class is a wrapper around the naive ListView widget.

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListCtrl.html